# Angular2 (final) get current ActivatedRoute in AppComponent

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to get the last route data in *AppComponent* in order to manipulate data visibility - display menu in all pages by default except some specific pages.

In order to do so, the relevant pages gets the following data in router configuration: `data: [ { showMenu: false }]`

Then I'm trying get the parameter in *AppComponent* using the following code:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(route.snapshot);
}
```

I'm browsing the matching url and getting **empty data**, but when I'm running the same code in the matching *ChildComponent* I do get the data.

My project looks as the following:

AppComponent:

> app.component.html -> contains the menu and the router-outlet
>
> app.module.ts -> imports ChildModule

ChildComponent:

> child.module.ts -> imports RouterModule
>
> child.routes.ts -> contains the router configuration with the data attribute

Please advise how to solve this issue and review if this solution is proper

Thanks!

Comment: According to the [current documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html) you can access the `data` attribute of the route with `route.data` which returns an `Observable` with your data.
Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: It is also empty in the AppComponent (and ChildComponent), I think the problem caused by the context of the routing and the mapping for the right component.

Comment: Could you provide a plunker of the code? I don't think I can help further without looking at the code, unfortunately.